# How can I change the Main Window with a button and run the events from another window Pyside6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

I want to change the Main Window through a button click, but when the main window change´s the event´s dont run.

The both window´s are already been created in qt Designer
here is the code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import  QObject
from PySide6.QtCore import  QCoreApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *

from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from ui_app import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_menu import Ui_MainWindow1
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.trocarpag)

    def trocarpag(self):
        if self.textuser.toPlainText() == "" :
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Preencha o Username!!!")
            msg.exec()
        elif self.textpass.toPlainText() == "" :
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("Preencha a Password!!!")
            msg.exec()
        else:
            ###Change the Main Window####`
             self.ui = Ui_MainWindow1()
             self.ui.setupUi(self)
            
if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Don't call `setupUi()` on the same instance. If you want to show multiple "pages", use QStackedWidget ("Stacked Widget") in Designer or by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line of code `self.ui = Ui_MainWindow1()` creates just a member variable in your object `window` of class `MainWindow`. There are no code that would replace widgets in current window or show new window instead.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: @StarterKit yes, there is, it's the `setupUi()` function that is created by the pyuic script.

Comment: Ok, it appears I'm not right here... need to make some test...